# Joining of two tables is not working

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. Table1 and Table2.

Table1 data:

```
 Id   org_id  start_date    end_date     month
'1', '46', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-31', 'January'
'2', '46', '2015-02-01', '2015-02-28', 'February'
'3', '46', '2015-03-01', '2015-03-31', 'March'
'4', '46', '2015-04-01', '2015-04-30', 'April'
'5', '46', '2015-05-01', '2015-05-31', 'May'
'6', '46', '2015-06-01', '2015-06-30', 'June'
'7', '46', '2015-07-01', '2015-07-31', 'July'
'8', '46', '2015-08-01', '2015-08-31', 'August'
'9', '46', '2015-09-01', '2015-09-30', 'September'
'10', '46', '2015-10-01', '2015-10-31', 'October'
'11', '46', '2015-11-01', '2015-11-30', 'November'
'12', '46', '2015-12-01', '2015-12-31', 'December'
```

Table2 data:

```
Id   org_id   from_date  emp_id
'48', '46', '2015-06-09'   1
'49', '46', '2015-06-09'   1
'50', '46', '2015-06-01'   2
'51', '46', '2015-05-20'   1
'56', '46', '2015-07-07'   2
```

This is my query:

```
select t1.month,count(t2.emp_id) as count
from Table1 t1
left outer join  Table2 t2 on t2.from_date between t1.start_date and t1.end_date
where t2.org_id=46 group by t1.month
```

Output i am getting is:

```
month   count
'July', '1'
'June', '3'
'May', '1'
```

Output i am expecting is:

```
 month    count
'January', '0'
'February', '0'
'March', '0'
'April', '0'
'May', '1'
'June', '3'
'July', '1'
'August', '0'
'September', '0'
'October', '0'
'November', '0'
'December', '0'
```

I have used left outer join. But all records from left table is not getting fetched.

Any help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the part of your `where`statament to the on clase:

```
select t1.month,count(t2.emp_id) as count
from Table1 t1
left outer join  Table2 t2 on t2.from_date between t1.start_date and t1.end_date
and t2.org_id=46 group by t1.month
```

If you do not do it you have a `inner join`

Comment: Can't i order it as my expected result? I used order by t1.month. but not working.

Comment: @0991 You have to use `order by FIELD(t1.month, 'January','February',...)` and so on.

Comment: @0991 you could also use `order by t1.id`

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
SELECT t1.month,COUNT(t2.emp_id) AS COUNT
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN  Table2 t2 ON t2.from_date BETWEEN t1.start_date AND t1.end_date
    AND t2.org_id=46 GROUP BY t1.month
```