# MySql query is not working as i expected

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a query. But it is not working as i expected.
Here is my query:

```
select mo.year,mo.month,count(emp_id)
from employee em
right outer join months mo on ifnull(em.joining_date,'2010-01-01') < mo.start_date 
and ifnull(em.relieving_date,'2050-01-01') > mo.end_date
 where em.bill=1 and em.org_id=8
group by mo.month
```

Here is my months table:

```
 id    start_date    end_date     month      year
'1', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-31', 'January', '2015'
'2', '2015-02-01', '2015-02-28', 'February', '2015'
'3', '2015-03-01', '2015-03-31', 'March', '2015'
'4', '2015-04-01', '2015-04-30', 'April', '2015'
'5', '2015-05-01', '2015-05-31', 'May', '2015'
'6', '2015-06-01', '2015-06-30', 'June', '2015'
'7', '2015-07-01', '2015-07-31', 'July', '2015'
'8', '2015-08-01', '2015-08-31', 'August', '2015'
'9', '2015-09-01', '2015-09-30', 'September', '2015'
'10', '2015-10-01', '2015-10-31', 'October', '2015'
'11', '2015-11-01', '2015-11-30', 'November', '2015'
'12', '2015-12-01', '2015-12-31', 'December', '2015'
```

Here is my employee table:

```
id    joining_date  relieving_date    bill      org_id  emp_id
1,       NULL,      NULL,           0,        8,        1
2, '2015-02-10',       NULL,        1,        8,       2
3, '2015-08-05', '2015-11-31',       1,       8,       3
```

This is my current output:

```
 year   org_id month  count(emp_id)
'2015', '8', 'April', '2'
'2015', '8', 'August', '2'
'2015', '8', 'December', '2'
'2016', '8', 'February', '1'
'2016', '8', 'January', '1'
'2015', '8', 'July', '2'
'2015', '8', 'June', '2'
'2015', '8', 'March', '2'
'2015', '8', 'May', '2'
'2015', '8', 'November', '2'
'2015', '8', 'October', '3'
'2015', '8', 'September', '3'
```

My expected output is:

```
 year   org_id month  count(emp_id)
'2015', '8', 'April', '1'
'2015', '8', 'August', '2'
'2015', '8', 'December', '1'
'2016', '8', 'February', '0'
'2016', '8', 'January', '0'
'2015', '8', 'July', '1'
'2015', '8', 'June', '1'
'2015', '8', 'March', '1'
'2015', '8', 'May', '1'
'2015', '8', 'November', '1'
'2015', '8', 'October', '2'
'2015', '8', 'September', '2'
```

Count is getting increased automatically if relieving date is not their.

Any help!!

Comment: Are `joining_date` and `relieving_date` of employee #1 `NULL` or the empty string? You listed them as the empty string in the data but you assume they are `NULL` in the query.

Comment: They are Null in table.

Comment: `'NULL'` is not the same as `NULL`. The question is more confusing now than it was before. If you want to make it clear, use quotes or apostrophes only around the values that are strings in the database. Don't enclose the numbers, the dates and the `NULL` values in quotes.

Comment: Remove the `GROUP BY` clause and the `COUNT(emp_id)` expression, run the query and check if it returns the expected set of rows.

Comment: @axiac question edited.  After removing group by and count expected result is not getting.

Comment: That was a hint on how to debug the query yourself, it is not a solution. Analyze the result set returned after the removal of `GROUP BY` to see if the join conditions are correct. When you manage to make the `JOIN` return the rows you need, put `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(emp_id)` back and that's the solution.

Comment: Where do the 2016 values come from? Also why do you expect noone to work for you in 2016 if you set the relieving_date to 2050? And why do you expect 2 people to work for you in August, if you do not count partial months?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joining of two tables is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884480/joining-of-two-tables-is-not-working)

Answer (score -1):

```
select mo.year, mo.month, count(emp_id)
from employee em
right outer join months mo 
on 
  ifnull(em.joining_date,'2050-01-01') < mo.start_date 
  and ifnull(em.relieving_date,'2050-01-01') > mo.end_date
where 
  em.bill=1 and em.org_id=8
group by mo.month
```

Comment: Can you please show me the difference between your query and the original query? (Besides the different date in the `ifnull(em.joining_date,...)`, which must be an error)

Comment: Their is no difference between both the queries other than date.

Comment: But that's exactly the trick :) If you want to have employees without joining_date to be not counted, you need to increase the default date for this case. The query itself is fine although I would suggest to switch the order of from and right join.

Comment: no, this was just a suggestion. use the different date and the result is correct